# Concatenacion de rutas con React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Estoy teniendo un inconveniente con React Router y una paginación. Si estoy en la raiz del proyecto y hago click en el boton siguiente me va a midominio.com/page/2 y asi sucesivamente. Esto es correcto.

Pero si estoy en midominio.com/categorias cuando doy click en siguiente me va a midominio.com/page/2 pero luego si doy anterior o siguiente comienza a concatenar las rutas de la forma midominio.com/page/2/page/1/page/2 y así sucesivamente.

Así estan las rutas:

```
<Route path="/categoria/:id/:slug/page/:page" exact>
  <Category />
</Route>
<Route path="/categoria/:id/:slug">
  <Category />
</Route>
```

A mi componente de paginación le paso como props la url actual, el array de productos traido de la api, la página actual y la cantidad de páginas:

```
<Pagination baseurl={`${urlActual}/`} pagina={pagina} productos={productsByTag} pageCount={pageCount}/>
```

En cuanto a los links de los botones dentro del componente de paginación están hechos de la siguiente manera:

```
 pagina ? (
    <Link to={`${baseUrl}page/${Number(pagina)+1}`}>
      <button className="btn btn-primary">Next</button>
    </Link>
  ):(
    <Link to={`${baseUrl}page/2`}>
      <button className="btn btn-primary">Prev</button>
    </Link>
   )
```

Alguna idea de por que podría estar pasando esto?

Comment: Podrías añadir el valor de urlActual?. En `react-router` si pones `/` al principio del `to` en el `Link` se hace de manera relativa desde la página que se encuentra. Si no pones `/` al principio de pone de forma absoluta sobre la aplicación web. Comprueba y me dices.

Comment: El valor de url actual lo tomo con useLocation().pathname;, pero me di cuenta que es un error, ya que eso es lo que me concatena las rutas porque siempre va a tomar la url del momento. Si pongo / al principio del to en el Link, en el root me funciona bien, pero si estoy sobre un directorio me envia al root.